# equivalent of getbounds

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the equivalent of map.getbounds() with the V3 ?
I suppose I must use b = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(pt1,pt2)
with pt1 and pt2 the origin and the end of the map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is map.getBounds()

See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map